# Apply PHP compare function to all elements in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, performance, algorithm, euclidean-distance

I'm building an algorithm that takes an euclidean coordinate—for example (-4, 2)—and searches through a large database table of other coordinates to find the closest coordinates (using euclidean  distance formula). Currently, my code looks like this:

```
$x = -4;
$y = 2;
$query = mysql_query('SELECT `x`, `y` FROM `myTable`');
$closest = PHP_INT_MAX;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $dist = distFormula($x, $y, $row[x], $row[y]);
    if($dist<$closest)
        $closest = $dist;
}
echo $closest;

distFormula($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2){
    return sqrt(pow($x2-$x1, 2)+pow($y2-$y1, 2));
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? My database table may be extremely large. Is there some way to do the comparison inside the query? Also, for the purpose of example, I used two-dimensions in this case, however in reality I intend to use high numbers of dimensions (longer coordinates).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you can do the calculation on the db side, but it's still going to be a full table scan...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can make such calculations in MySQL within the query. Try this:

```
$query = <<<SQL
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT $x originX, $y originY, x closestX, y closestY, SQRT(
       ($x-x)*($x-x)
     + ($y-y)*($y-y)
  ) dist FROM `myTable`) a ORDER BY dist DESC LIMIT 1
SQL;
```

Make sure the last line is by itself, no other characters at the start or end.

It should give the distance within the 'dist' column in the results

Here's an example with 3 dimensions...

```
$query = <<<SQL
  SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT 
         $x originX, $y originY, $z originZ, 
         x closestX, y closestY, z closestZ 
         SQRT(
           ($x-x)*($x-x)
         + ($y-y)*($y-y)
         + ($z-z)*($z-z)
  ) dist FROM `myTable`) a ORDER BY dist DESC LIMIT 1
SQL;
```

Comment: Not _such comparisons_, but such **calculations** - in your example

Comment: He needs the shortest distance, so there should be a `MIN` in there somewhere.

Comment: @Bart Friederichs AFAIK SQL's [`MIN`/`LEAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) function doesn't work with columns, only with values. So anyway comparisons have to perform in PHP

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! :) Three questions: first, because every row must be checked, this will always be O(n) time at best, right? Second, is doing it like this in MySQL actually faster than doing it in PHP? Lastly, given some `$n`, how would this be adjusted to implement n-dimensional Euclidean distance formula, like I mentioned at the end of my post? A loop in the MySQL would be needed, right? See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance

Comment: Good point @BartFriederichs, however hindmost is right. I've made the example more robust so that it only returns the closest result and also gives the origin X/Y and closest X/Y (you could also get the ID of that result row if you needed...)

Comment: @UnknownUser regarding your questions: yes, every row will be checked. That's unavoidable I'm afraid. If you're concerned about optimization I would raise a different question for that. You could for example cluster the points into a virtual 'grid' and then only check the nearby 'cells'. This video explains the concept at a high level http://youtu.be/2-V8fcYCG3s?t=1m13s. The SQL query calculation is definitely faster than PHP because MySQL is optimized for dealing with bulk calculation. Yes if you had 'n' dimensions you would need a loop within the query.

Comment: Thanks a lot @1owk3y! I will definitely look into the grid concept—that sounds like a great idea! I will mark your answer as accepted. But do you think you could give an example of implementing the n-dimensional distance formula in the MySQL query via a loop?

Comment: Sorry just about to leave the house, but I've added a 3D example in my original answer. As you can see it's not too much more complicated to add any number of dimensions. I'd suggest an array of your points like array('x'=>10, 'y'=>5, 'z'=>3, 'a'=>12, ...), use a foreach loop to get the names of each 'dimension' and output a query that uses the names of the dimensions to build the query

Comment: @1owk3y Oh, I see. So the best way to loop is to dynamically generate the MySQL query with PHP?

Comment: Yes thats right. If you needed to, for example, see how many dimensions needed to be compared with prior, just fire a quick SQL query beforehand to get the column names or something